# read in file bubble sort write out in C

Tags: c, string

I am trying to write this code and I seem to be getting segmentation errors.
I am stuck can anyone help.

I realize it is a bit messy at the moment.

I am trying to open a text file, send too bubble sort and send to an output file and write.

Do you know where I am going wrong here?

(I am using pointers I say using more like I am messing it up big time)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int readIndata(char*fileName, char* words[]);

int writeOutData(const char* filename, char* words[], int N ); 
void bSort(char* words[], int N);/* for some reason i thought  output file needed to be defined in the prototype and I was getting too few arguments error*/


 int main(void){
   /*Define variables*/  
 char inFilename[200]; /* This is the amout of words in the file name*/
 char outFilename[200];
 char *words[ 10]; /*the amount of words in a file to take in*/
 int N= sizeof(words)/ sizeof(words[0]); /* call to bubble sort dereferencing words to find size ;*/


printf("\n Enter File Name");

scanf("%c", &inFilename);



bSort(words, N);

printf("\n Enter File output Name");
scanf("%c", &outFilename);/* i should change this name */
writeOutData(outFilename,words, N);

 return 0;

 }

int readIndata(char*fileName, char* words[]){


    FILE *cfPtr;
    int i=0;
    unsigned int N = sizeof(*words)/ sizeof(*words[0]);
    //fgets(str,20, inputFile);
    if ((cfPtr = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL) {
      puts ("File could Not Be opened");

    }
    else{

        for(i=0; i< N-1 && i!= EOF; i++){// carry out passing for the size of the file until EOF is reached
            fscanf(cfPtr, "%c",&words[i]);// scan in the file and strings and assing pass them to the words array 
        }
      /*bSort(words[i], N);*/ /* pass the words array and the number of words to bubble sort*/
      return 0;
    }
        /* pass this to the words function to go to bubblesort*/

fclose(cfPtr);


}


void bSort(char* words[], int N){// lines is the number of words

int i, j;
    char *swap;
    for (i = 0 ; i < ( N - 1 ); i++) {
    for (j = 0 ; j < N - i - 1; j++) {
      if (strcmp(words[j],words[j+1])>0) //Compare 2 strings and swap https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcmp
      {
        // Swaping
        swap       = words[j];
        words[j]   = words[j+1];
        words[j+1] = swap;
      }
    }
  }
}


int writeOutData(const char* fileName, char* words[], int N){

FILE *cfPtr;
int i=0;

cfPtr =fopen(fileName, "w");

for (i=0;i <N-1;i++){/*n-1 becauese EOF is last */
  fprintf(cfPtr, "%s\n", words[i]);
} 
fclose(cfPtr);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sure about using `&` in `int N= sizeof(&words)/ sizeof(&words[0]);`?  Size of address / size of address?  I'd expect that to be 1.

Comment: thanks, sorry i am only learning pointers so this is new to me

Comment: I suspect you want `int N = sizeof words/ sizeof words[0])`.

Comment: well I want to find the number of words in the txt file so I can pass it to another function as n and sort them alphabetically, i am making amess of it

Comment: Code declares and defines `readIndata()`, but never calls it.  Need to use `readIndata()` in `main()`.  I recommend you post a _clear_ precise question.  So far, this post has no question.